# register an imported bundle from my own bundle in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, init

I've created a bundle (via generate:bundle) which is could use an imported one.
For example, my bundle's name is EmailBundle. This will use sending functions from another bundle, name is SmtpBundle (imported from composer).

SmtpBundle has configuration parameters in config.yml, and has to be init in Appkernel.php via registerBundles().

This last step is what I want to left. Is there any way to register SmtpBundle from my EmailBundle, or something like this?

Regards,
R.

Comment: Basically no.  Just not something Symfony was designed to do.  You might be able to have your email bundle treat the smtp bundle as a library and create create your own smtp services inside of the email bundle.  That would eliminate the need to actually register the smtp bundle.  But it's probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: You can use `StmpBundle`s features directly from your bundle after you register on `AppKernel.php` and configure.

Comment: Turdaliev Nursultan: Yes, that is exactly I said before. But I try to avoid this. What I looking for is a method when only one bundle registering is necessary (for my bundle) and that will initialize requirements